# Minimizing database requests for moves of a chess game?

Tags: database

I'm writing a webapp for chess which, for a given move and a database of games, shows all the moves that follow from that move. Pretty much what this website has already done: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/explorer

The database will have a table of "moves" which have a link to the previous move in the sequence. Finding the moves following a given move (x) can then be done by searching the table for any "move" that has "previousMove" as x. This is simple enough, but I can't think of an efficient way to add to the moves table from a given game of chess. My algorithm so far is:

```
prevMove = null
for move in game.moves:
    dbMove = getMoveFromDB(move, prevMove) 
    if not dbMove
        dbMove = createDBMove()
        dbMove.prevMove = prevMove
    prevMove = dbMove
```

For an average of 40 moves per chess game, this means that there would be 40+ database reads to import a game. Is this inevitable or is there a better way to import the moves from a game into the database?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't bring back more than one move from the database with a single query?

Comment: I think 40 reads over the typical time of a game (many minutes), I think is pretty insignificant compared to the challenge of storing and accessing that large a volume of data sensibly.

Comment: @whatsisname, the games would be imported from PGN files which contain the whole game rather than adding the moves of a game in real time.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? The website that you linked maintains statistics about sequences of moves, and lets you navigate those moves. Given that navigation takes human-scale time, there's *no reason to care* about 40 database reads: the time they take is immaterial.

Comment: Or are you simply looking for a way to uniquely identify each move (ie, the database key)? If that's the case, then you need to represent the state of the board. One approach would be to use a row-wise traversal that identifies each piece on the board, something like `"A8BRB8BK...H1WR"` (I combine piece name and location because that takes a maximum of 128 characters but will decrease as the game proceeds; you could also use a fixed-size format with just the piece names, taking 128 characters for each move).

Comment: If you somehow think that you can load all possible moves in one query -- or even store them in a database -- [it ain't gonna happen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_number).